# Get accurate address from current user position flutter

Tags: android, flutter, location

Am currently using the [Google Geocoding Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_397052992730-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7E%20Places%20%7C%20EXA%20%7C%20Geocoding%20API-KWID_43700049595992247-aud-903284319780%3Akwd-301485311002-userloc_1010285&utm_term=KW_geocoding%20api-ST_geocoding%20api&gclid=CjwKCAiAz4b_BRBbEiwA5XlVVigDn-0CY8JcVCSoRtMPmAc6efH5eDGLvFadEVMJS3PN-SmVW8cGoBoC1vcQAvD_BwE) to convert latlng coordinates to current user address shown to the user. However, I realised its not accurate as expected as it doesn't give exact description of user address. Is there any other api I could use to achieve a more accurate address? Or can I do the conversion with google Places API instead of geocoding API?

Answer (score 0):

GPS to address is still an in-exact science.  Even going the other way can get dicey sometimes.  That's why delivery businesses have you enter the address explicitly.

So no, you're probably getting the best you can with the API you're using, unless your device is set to quick-and-inaccurate rather than slow-and-more-precise.

Answer (score 0):

Give Location Package a try for getting current location : https://pub.dev/packages/location